# unauthorized: authentication required when push my image

Tags: docker

Details below

I login docker succeeded;

```
@ubuntu:~$ docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username (******):
Password:
Login Succeeded
```

but when push a image then :

```
@ubuntu:~$ docker push nodejsubuntu
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/library/nodejsubuntu]
9ce2f4fd17ae: Preparing
0cad5e07ba33: Preparing
48373480614b: Preparing
055757a19384: Preparing
c6f2b330b60c: Preparing
c8a75145fcc4: Waiting
unauthorized: authentication required
```

docker version:

```
Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638`
```

and my ~/.docker/config.json below:

```
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
      "auth": "*****"
    }
  }
}
```

use command :

```
sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep docker
```

I got the message:

```
time="2016-09-14T09:37:36.511442483Z" level=error msg="Attempting next endpoint for push after error: unauthorized: authentication required"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to push to your namespace. You are trying to push to the root namespace, which you do not have permission to do:

```
docker push <your-username>/nodejsubuntu
```

For example:

```
docker push sethvargo/nodejsubuntu
```

Comment: Thanks very much.The reason is that I create the wrong image name ,not with <my-username>/nodejsubuntu,only nodejsubuntu.

Comment: I have been pulling my hairs off from last 24 hours and this solved the problem.